# JavaScript setTimout() that continues after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has icons that change color when clicked. After an hour, I want these icons to change back to the initial color. With my current code, the icons will change back when the page refreshes.
Can this be accomplished with JavaScript? In my example below I used a 10 second timer for testing:

```js
document.querySelector(".table-el").onclick = e => {
  if(e.target.tagName=="A")
  e.target.classList.add("visited");
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    e.target.classList.remove("visited"); 
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
button.edit-icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FF8800;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.table-el a.view-icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #0e47a2;
  transition: .3s;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.table-el a.view-icon.visited {
  opacity: .5;
}

button.delete-icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #cc0001;
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://intranet.msisurfaces.com/commons/css/NEXTGEN-Compact-v1.2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container-fluid mt-5 table-el">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="CompactGridView" cellspacing="0" rules="all" Border="0" border="0" id="CompactGridView"
        style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="CompactGridViewPagination-right">
          <td colspan="12">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">2</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">3</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">4</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">5</a></td>
                <!-- <div class="float-left">
                  <img src="img/excel-40x40-white-space.png" title="Download as .XLS" alt="Download as Excel" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                  <img src="img/csv-40x40-white-space.png" title="Download as .CSV" alt="Download as CSV" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                  <img src="img/acrobat-40x40-white-space.png" title="Download as .PDF" alt="Download as .PDF" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                </div> -->
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewHead-alt">
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"></a><input type="checkbox" /></th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Name</a></th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Position</a></th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Status</a></th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Office</a></th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Type</a> </th>
          <th scope="col"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Start Date</a></th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">View/Edit/Delete</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accounting</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>Los Angeles, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right pr-2">11/28/2012</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>London, England</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right pr-2">11/28/2007</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-inactive fs-12" style="background-color: #a5a5a5; color: white;">Inactive</span></td>
          <td>San Francisco, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Contract</td>
          <td class="text-right">01/01/2008</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>London, England</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">10/13/2012</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>Los Angeles, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">04/01/2019</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>New York, NY USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">12/02/2016</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>Los Angeles, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">08/15/2001</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-info fs-12">Family Leave</span></td>
          <td>New York, NY USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">06/01/2017</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>Salt Lake City, Utah USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">03/01/2019</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Front-End Developer</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>Los Angeles, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">07/01/2020</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewRow">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success fs-12">Active</span></td>
          <td>San Diego, California USA</td>
          <td class="text-center">Full-time</td>
          <td class="text-right">02/13/2011</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="view-icon">&#xf06e;</a><button class="edit-icon">&#xf044;</button><button class="delete-icon">&#xf2ed;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="CompactGridViewPagination-right">
          <td colspan="12">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">2</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">3</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">4</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;">5</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use actual time and sessionStorage

Comment: You could use the current time + 1 hours and localStorage instead, since the user might close the browser and reopen it again later on. If you take this approach, you can set a property in the localStorage that says the exact time the icon should change back (when it is clicked + 1 hour) instead of setting an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the code from your question and using @mplungjan solution:

```js
 document.querySelector(".table-el").onclick = e => {
  if(e.target.tagName=="A") e.target.classList.add("visited");
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    e.target.classList.remove("visited"); 
    sessionStorage.removeItem("tableElATimer");
  }, 10000);
  sessionStorage.setItem("tableElATimer", (Date.now() + 10000))
}
// I'm trying to grab an older timer
let oldTimer = sessionStorage.getItem("tableElATimer");
// If I find it and it's in the future (you can remove this costrain if you need to)
if (oldTimer !== null && oldTimer > Date.now()) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    e.target.classList.remove("visited"); 
    sessionStorage.removeItem("tableElATimer");
  }, oldTimer - Date.now());
}
```

Comment: It seems to work. I just need to figure out how to keep the icons with the "visited" class after reloading the page